# Why does Array(n).fill([]) not the same as hardcoding the array or using a for loop to create that array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this happen?
If you execute this code you will see what is printed in the comments.
I had assumed that A1, A2 and A3 would all be the same things.

```
const A1 = Array(3).fill([]);
const A2 = [[], [], []];
const A3 = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    A3.push([]);
}
console.log(A1 == A2 || A1 == A3 || A2 == A3); // False
```

In fact, A1 in particular is doing really weird things as highlighted below.

```
A1[0].push(5);
console.log(A1); // [ [ 5 ], [ 5 ], [ 5 ] ]

A2[0].push(5);
console.log(A2); // [ [ 5 ], [], [] ]

A3[0].push(5);
console.log(A3); // [ [ 5 ], [], [] ]
```

Comment: Using `Array(3).fill([]);` will fill your array with references to the same single array in memory. Your other examples create 3 unique arrays in memory

Comment: That’s two independent questions: the first one is a duplicate of [Why doesn't equality check work with arrays](/q/30820611/4642212), the second one is a duplicate of [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](/q/35578478/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

the `fill` method of `Array` fills the array (or a given range of indices in the array) with the same value

that means when you write the line `Array(3).fill([])` it actually puts the same array created using `[]` in all the indices of the array, so editing the array in one place, affects all indices (since they all point to the same array `[]`)

Answer (score 3):

Its because every element in A1 is the same array

its like:

```
let a = [];
let A1 = [a,a,a];
let b0 = [], b1 = [], b2 = []
let A2 = [b0, b1, b2]
```

Edit:

when you change A1[0] you change a

Answer (score 2):

When using [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) :

> if the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will
> reference that object

So if we modify a slot, all the slots will have the same value because they refer to the same object.